# portia (scrapy/slybot) errors on windows

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapinghub, portia

i installed portia and got it to work i annotated some websites (looks really good)
but when i try to run the spiders i get some errors and nothing gets crawled

im running python 2.7.6 on win 7

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>python portiacrawl C:\portia\slyd\data\projects\new_project
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "portiacrawl", line 7, in <module>
execfile(__file__)
File "C:\portia\slybot\bin\portiacrawl", line 56, in <module>
main()
File "C:\portia\slybot\bin\portiacrawl", line 54, in main
subprocess.call(command_spec)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] O sistema nÒo conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado
```

Comment: From that stack trace, it looks as if portia is calling a sub-process and it is returning a Windows error regarding locale?

Answer (score 0):

I am troubleshooting portia on Windows 8.1 and encountered the same error, exactly.
Try running 'python portiacrawl' by itself to determine if there is a subsequent menu. You should be able to see Help info on 'portiacrawl'. I suspect that you need to name the [spider] & [options] as well as change the terminal directory to see the output from the crawler. 
I suggest trying the following but rename [spider] to actual name of your spider w/o brackets:

1. Enter into terminal: C:\portia\slyd\data\projects <------Change to proper directory in cmd
2. Make sure you are in the terminal directory "C:\portia\slyd\data\projects" 
   The Cmd propmpt should look like: C:\portia\slyd\data\projects> <----waiting for portia initiation.
3. Enter into terminal:
   python portiacrawl C:\portia\slyd\data\projects\new_project [spider] -t csv -o test.csv; 
    or,
   python portiacrawl  [spider] -t csv -o test.csv
4. Report back. I am curious as to the terminal response. Did it initiate portiacrawl & return "access is denied."